# How to map the response for the REST request by Apache camel HTTP component

Tags: apache-camel

I have implemented following route with Apache camel XML mode.

```
<restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="json" contextPath="/abc-esb/rest" port="8181"> 
    <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true" />
    <dataFormatProperty key="json.in.disableFeatures" value="FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES" />
</restConfiguration>

<rest path="/service-http" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
    <put type="com.abc.abcd.esb.models.UserServiceMapping" uri="/create">
        <route>
            <setHeader headerName="Authorization">
                <simple>Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setBody>
                <simple>
                    {"SystemUserDetails":{"userName":"${body.objectDetails.userName}",
                    "password": "${body.objectDetails.password}"}}
                </simple>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="http://192.168.1.20:8081/abcd/services/UserServiceRest/V1.0/users/create?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
        </route>
    </put>
</rest>
```

Functionality happens as expected. But camel returns HTTP 500 mentioning following error.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class
>   org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream
>   and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid
>   exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)

When I analyze a tcp dump related to this scenario, I found this HTTP 500 occurred when trying to mapping the `{"status" : "Success"}` response from the external webservice.

**Content of the UserServiceMapping class**

```
    private String serviceName;
    private String serviceMethod;
    private String mappedServiceObject;
    private SystemUserDetails objectDetails;
    // private StatusDetails statusDetails;

    public String getMappedServiceObject() {
        return mappedServiceObject;
    }

    public void setMappedServiceObject(String mappedServiceObject) {
        this.mappedServiceObject = mappedServiceObject;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    public String getServiceMethod() {
        return serviceMethod;
    }

    public void setServiceMethod(String serviceMethod) {
        this.serviceMethod = serviceMethod;
    }

    public SystemUserDetails getObjectDetails() {
        return objectDetails;
    }

    public void setObjectDetails(SystemUserDetails objectDetails) {
        this.objectDetails = objectDetails;
    }

    /*
     * public StatusDetails getStatusDetails() { return statusDetails; }
     * 
     * public void setStatusDetails(StatusDetails statusDetails) {
     * this.statusDetails = statusDetails; }
     */
```

[Request response flow of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ghhR.jpg)

Comment: As you have problems finding a serialization implementation, have you tried adding one to your dependencies? Usually something like `camel-jackson`, `jackson-core`, `jackson-databind` and/or `org.json` can be found in camel projects which make use of the REST DSL

Comment: @Udara Seneviratne, can you please try to add `resultType="java.lang.String"` attribute in `simple` tag. or add line like this `<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>` after `setBody` tag.

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your suggestion. But issue still exist. Is there a way to map the response for the endpoint request ?

Comment: @Aleksei Bulgak Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion too but issue is still there.

Comment: @UdaraSeneviratne Could you add the content of your `UserServiceMapping` class?

Comment: @Roman Vottner, Yes sure. I have included the content.

Comment: How ever up to now I couldn't find an exact reason for this issue but I could by-pass the problem by setting Accept: application/xml other than Accept: application/json in my external REST client which makes the initial REST request. (REST service endpoint in other end configured to produce both json and xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How ever up to now I couldn't find an exact reason for this issue but I could by-pass the problem by setting Accept: application/xml other than Accept: application/json in my external REST client which makes the initial REST request. (REST service endpoint in other end configured to produce both json and xml)